# how to change the marker image in google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

i have 20 markers from which i want to show 10 markers with similar marker and with similar label ("A") , and other 10  i want to show with different marker image and different label ("B") . im getting all the marker with same image and same label

js fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/9yq8y1p2/4/

```
var initMap =    function () {
    var labels = '0123456789';
    var labelIndex = 0;
    var myLatLng = { lat: 17.446507, lng: 78.383033, deviceId: 'a' };
    var citymap = {
         hyderabad: {
              center: { lat: 17.446507, lng: 78.383033 },
              population: 5000
         }
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
         zoom: 18,
         center: myLatLng,
    });
}
```

Comment: Fiddle doesn't display single marker on map, please update it.

Answer (score 0):

```
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: location,
                        icon: condition ? image_1 :image_2,
                        map: map
                    });
```

You can mention the condition for which you want image_1 as marker.